# Is it correct to call an exchange-traded note a type of ETF?

Tags: investing

I'm trying to find out what the types of ETFs are and ran into some confusion: A webpage (http://etfdb.com/portfolio-management/the-7-different-etf-structures/) lists ETNs as a type of ETF. But an Investopedia page (http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/etn.asp) says that ETNs are "like" ETFs. Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Summary

They're exchange traded debt, basically, not funds.

E.g. from the [NYSE](https://www.nyse.com/products/etp-funds-etn):

> An exchange-traded note (ETN) is a senior unsecured debt obligation designed to track the total return of an underlying market index or other benchmark, minus investor fees.

Whereas an ETF, in some way or another, is an equity product - which doesn't mean that they can only expose you to equity, but that they themselves are a company that you buy shares in.

---

#### Debt ETN/ETF example

[FCOR](https://screener.fidelity.com/ftgw/etf/goto/snapshot/snapshot.jhtml?symbols=FCOR) for example is a bond ETF, basically a company whose sole purpose is to own a basket of bonds.  Contrast that to [DTYS](http://www.ipathetn.com/US/16/en/instruments.app#/details/259108), a bear Treasury ETN, which is described as

> The ETNs are unsecured debt obligations of the issuer, Barclays Bank PLC, and are not, either directly or indirectly, an obligation of or guaranteed by any third party.

Also from [Barclays](http://www.ipathetn.com/US/16/en/static/education-fundamentals.app) site:

> Because the iPath ETNs are debt securities, they do not have any voting rights.

FCOR on the other hand is [some sort of company owned/managed by a Fidelity trust](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1562565/000119312515156779/0001193125-15-156779-index.htm), though my EDGAR skills are rusty.

> AGREEMENT made this 18th day of
>   September, 2014, by and between Fidelity Merrimack Street Trust, a Massachusetts business trust which may issue one or more series of shares of beneficial interest (hereinafter called the “Trust”), on behalf of Fidelity Corporate
>   Bond ETF (hereinafter called the “Fund”), and Fidelity Investments Money Management, Inc., a New Hampshire corporation (hereinafter called the “Adviser”) as set forth in its entirety below.

Comment: That's confusing because, to my knowledge, there are plenty of bond ETFs.

Comment: @WalletSage if you look at a bond ETF, FCOR for instance, you create and redeem units by delivering or receiving the basket of bonds the ETF holds - the ETF itself is a corporation/trust that owns the portfolio of bonds, and you own equity in that corporation.  Let me add some color to my answer.